# Get collection in laravel based on parent relationship

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

i am trying to get an eloquent version of the query below

```
select * from transactions inner join currencies on transactions.currency_id=currencies.id where transactions.user_id=1 and currencies.currency_type=0
```

This is my transaction model

```
class Transaction extends Model
{
  
   public function currency(): BelongsTo
   {
    return $this->belongsTo(Currency::class);
   }
}
```

and my currency model

```
class Currency extends Model
{

  public function transactions(): HasMany
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Transaction::class);
  }
}
```

this is what i tried so far

```
Transaction::where('currency.currency_type', 0)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

use `with`.

```
  Transaction::with('currency',function($query){
    $query->where('currency_type',0);
    })->get();
```

if you want to return transaction only if currency exist then use `whereHas`

```
Transaction::with('currency')->whereHas('currency',function($query){
    $query->where('currency_type',0);
    })->get();
```